# Is there a way to have a base class for a razor's code behind?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have CampaignPage.razor:

```
@page "/Manager/Campaign"
@implements IDisposable

<PageTitle>Campaign</PageTitle>

<EditForm EditContext="EditContext"
          OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmitAsync"
          OnInvalidSubmit="HandleInvalidSubmitAsync"
          Context="EditFormContext">
...
```

And I have CampaignPage.razor.cs:

```
    public partial class CampaignPage
    {
...
```

Is there some way I can have:

```
    public partial class CampaignPage : OrganizationPage
    {
...
```

I tried doing this as:

```
public class OrganizationPage : ComponentBase
{
...
```

but that got me compiler errors.

Comment: And yes, I try to do everything I can to avoid duplicate code. Admittedly, sometimes too much...

Comment: How about `@inherits` on the markup page?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there, since you are using partial class for CampaignPage so you also need to inherit you CampaignPage.razor from OrganizationPage

Your CampaignPage.razor should look like this

```
@page "/Manager/Campaign"
@implements IDisposable    
@inherits OrganizationPage
```

Comment: Curiously it works the other way -- if you only use the @Inherits in CampaignPage you do not need to also declare the base class in its code behind class ... this may be a quirk of the compiler (for now) - it seems enough to me if one of the partial classes declares the base class (and none of them declare different base classes) ... but it also does no harm to have the base class declared in both partial classes here.